# mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wst\xxx.php on line 28

Tags: php, mysqli

i am tryimg to add new row into my table which is the combination of 2 rows
i tried writing this code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>LoginDB</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        $con=  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");

        if(!$con)
       {
           die('not connected');
       }
            $con=  mysqli_query($con, "select frstname,lastname,hello as (frstname+lastname) from registration");

       ?>
        <div>
            <td>Login Page Database</td>
         <table border="1">
            <th> First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>hello</th>


        <?php

             while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($con))

             {
                 ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['frstname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['hello']; ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
             }
             ?>
             </table>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but i am getting an error
can any one can rewrite the code if possible or can tell where the error lies.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement throws an syntax error

> "select frstname,lastname,hello as (frstname+lastname) from registration"

So you don't get an result set, but `false` as boolean.

Correct your statement. The part `hello as (frstname+lastname)` is wrong. 
Check the mysql-syntax about [string concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and using the `as` alias.

Should be like the following line (assuming the col and table names are correct)

```
select frstname,lastname, concat(frstname,lastname) as hello from registration
```

Comment: in case it the fields are numbers what to do??